# self.title is returning (null)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Using a navigation controller, I am pushing a new view and setting the title of it dynamically:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
int countryIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
NSString *selectedCountry = [[countrysData objectAtIndex: countryIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
scheduleState *scheduleStateViewController = [[scheduleState alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:scheduleStateViewController animated:YES];    
scheduleStateViewController.title = selectedCountry;    

[scheduleStateViewController release];
```

CountryData being a mutable  array created from an xml feed.

Now when I go to the next view, it displays correctly, however when I try to do an NSLog inside the new viewController, it logs as (null):

```
NSLog(@"The title is: %@", self.navigationItem.title);
```

2009-10-27 11:30:20.416 myApp[50289:20b] The title is: (null)

I need to use the title as a parameter for grabbing a web service query...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you pushing a view or a view controller? You can't push a view. What kind of class is scheduleState?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to log the title in the controller's `-viewDidLoad` or something similar, it's failing because you're setting the title *after* pushing the view controller. Set the title of the controller before you push it and it should work better.

The only other reason it could be nil is if the `selectedCountry` variable is nil. Log that directly to make sure.